# What is the latest version of NuGet that works with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am trying to add a nuget package (PiranhaCMS) to my VS2012/NET45 project. The nuget package itself depends on AutoMapper. When I try to install I get the message

'AutoMapper' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'

I'm confused because Piranha itself depends on NET45 not NETStandard. Research indicates I might need a later version of nuget. Having invoked nuget update -self on the nuget.exe in the .nuget folder under the solution, I tried again but got the same message.

What's further confusing me is nuget.exe is on 4.2.0.4168 but VS2012's Help, About dialog says the NuGet Package Manager is on 2.8.60318.667.

What I need to know is, can I get this package installed into this VS2012 solution? If so, how? If I can't do I need to move to VS017 so I can use a later version of NuGet which will install the package for me, even if the solution continues to target NET45?

Comment: 2.8.60318.667 is already the last version for VS2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I get this package installed into this VS2012 solution? If so, how?

We could not get this package installed into this Visual Studio 2012. That because **full NetStandard and NetCoreApp support for VS2013** (NuGet version is 2.12) and the latest version for Visual Studio 2012 is 2.8.6. so we will get that error when we install the package "`PiranhaCMS`" by Visual Studio 2012.
You can refer to the [NuGet release note for 2.12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.12) for detail info.

[image]

> If I can't do I need to move to VS017 so I can use a later version of
>   NuGet which will install the package for me, even if the solution
>   continues to target NET45?

Yes, you can install that package to the solution continues to target NET45 on Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Leo. Looks like we'll be moving to VS2017 later in the year.